# Sed error "sed: no input files"

Tags: perl, sed, command-line-arguments

I have the script which cleans up the the pattern in the file supplied as the argument.

The "file1" that needs clean up and the script lies at the same place.When I pass "file1" as argumenit is echoed well but at the 
time of the execution of the sed command it gives the following error:

```
-sh-3.2$ ./temp.pl file1.txt

File provided as the argument : file1.txt
sed: no input files
```

My script is:

```
my $logfile = $ARGV[0];
print "File provided as the argument : $logfile \n";
$cmd = q(sed -i '/Job will shutdown./d' $logfile);
$n = system($cmd);
```

Comment: It is good to indicate that your issue is solved by accepting an answer that was useful.

Answer (score 4):

Changue your quoting system:

```
$cmd = "sed -i '/Job will shutdown./d' $logfile";
```

Or:

```
$cmd = qq(sed -i '/Job will shutdown./d' $logfile);
```

Check http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=quotes+in+Perl

PD: **This task could be done natively in `perl`.**

Comment: Upvoted for advising on avoiding an additional tool. In fact this is one of the strong suits of Perl.